# How to mapReduce a collection with changing interval to support an avearage and trend dashboard?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

Consider the following sales data from a mongoDb sales collection (`product_id` points to the full product document):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4be63122ffe0284ef7041"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bcc8a4e46302c325e03e"), "dateTime" : 1555349091321, "quantity" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4be89122ffe0284ef7045"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5c374b7c183973020f6f164d"), "dateTime" : 1555349129818, "quantity" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4beb7122ffe0284ef7049"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bce4a4e46302c325e040"), "dateTime" : 1555349175057, "quantity" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4d212122ffe0284ef7096"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68b9b2a4e46302c325e01c"), "dateTime" : 1555354130281, "quantity" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb608501bd531027c98a66b"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bce4a4e46302c325e040"), "dateTime" : 1555433552312, "quantity" : 1500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb608d91bd531027c98a66f"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bce4a4e46302c325e040"), "dateTime" : 1555433689700, "quantity" : 1500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb6095a1bd531027c98a671"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bcc8a4e46302c325e03e"), "dateTime" : 1555433818444, "quantity" : 800 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb6099f1bd531027c98a673"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5c374b7c183973020f6f164d"), "dateTime" : 1555433887589, "quantity" : 1000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb60a161bd531027c98a677"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5c374b7c183973020f6f164d"), "dateTime" : 1555434006640, "quantity" : 1000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb60a331bd531027c98a67b"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bcc8a4e46302c325e03e"), "dateTime" : 1555434035074, "quantity" : 800 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb60cbc1bd531027c98a67d"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bcc8a4e46302c325e03e"), "dateTime" : 1555434684615, "quantity" : 200 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb60d311bd531027c98a67f"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bcc8a4e46302c325e03e"), "dateTime" : 1555434801277, "quantity" : 200 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb6195e1bd531027c98a6ae"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bce4a4e46302c325e040"), "dateTime" : 1555437918333, "quantity" : 5900 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb6199b1bd531027c98a6b0"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bcc8a4e46302c325e03e"), "dateTime" : 1555437979763, "quantity" : 1900 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb619c01bd531027c98a6b2"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5c374b7c183973020f6f164d"), "dateTime" : 1555438016908, "quantity" : 900 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb61a0e1bd531027c98a6b6"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bd59a4e46302c325e045"), "dateTime" : 1555438094303, "quantity" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb61a531bd531027c98a6ba"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5cb612911bd531027c98a681"), "dateTime" : 1555438163956, "quantity" : 1300 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb61abb1bd531027c98a6be"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5cb612911bd531027c98a681"), "dateTime" : 1555438267980, "quantity" : 1300 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb61e4d1bd531027c98a6d2"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bcc8a4e46302c325e03e"), "dateTime" : 1555439181478, "quantity" : 350 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cb6205a1bd531027c98a6e4"), "product_id" : ObjectId("5b68bcc8a4e46302c325e03e"), "dateTime" : 1555439706069, "quantity" : 350 }
```

`dateTime` is the transaction dateTime using Javascript's `Date.now()` function.

At the user side, I have a sales Dashboard:
[image]

User information available:

1. An "average sale quantity" indicator between a user defined interval (this month, today, yesterday, free interval, typing start date - end date)
2. A trend os the same indicator "average sale quantity" from the historical interval choosen. In example, if the user chooses "today", the trend is on daily basis. If the user chooses "month", the trend is in a month basis, and so on. If the user picks a custom interval, then it work in the closest interval (hour from within same day, days from withing week or month, months on within year)
3. If the user clicks on the indicator, a grid comes up with all the related records, and the user can change item quantities (and that will reflect to the whole indicators)

I have thousands of records and I will be building the mapReduce function to support that dashboard, where I would like to ask:

a) I don't want to run mapReduce every time the user changes the interval as this will take long, but I can't see how I will store different interval combinations in a result collection. So, what is the approach in case the user has free configuration of the start and end of the interval that mapReduce will work with.

b) The same way, for every interval I will have different data interval for trends. How can I accomplish that in the result collection?

c) What should I do in case the user changes data. Run a new mapReduce immeidately for all intervals not covered?